# Extending existing protocol to conform to another protocol

Tags: swift3, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Hello my goal here is to extend (in swift 3) a protocol I have in a framework to conform to another Protocol

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}
protocol SomeOtherProtocol {}
extension SomeOtherProtocol: SomeProtocol {}
```

The problem here is that I get an error: "Extension of protocol 'SomeOtherProtocol' cannot have an inheritance clause"
If this is not possible how do I achieve such thing or what's the "swift way"?

Comment: That's just not possible. Consider what that would mean: Say I had a class `C` which conforms to `SomeOtherProtocol `. When you extend  `SomeOtherProtocol` with a conformance to `SomeProtocol`, `C` will be unable to conform after this change.

Comment: Ah that's a good point. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to go around and extend the concrete types that conform to `SomeOtherProtocol` and make them conform to `SomeProtocol` on a case-by-case basis