# Express that all types conforming to one protocol conform to another protocol as well

Tags: swift, protocols

I have two protocols, `PA` and `PB`, where the requirements of `PB` are a subset of those of `PA`. I don't control `PA`. I'd like to express the fact that any instance conforming to `PA` also conforms to `PB`, but I can't figure out how to do so. I tried:

```
extension PA: PB {}
```

but the compiler errors. Here's a complete example:

```
protocol PA { func sayHello() }
protocol PB {}

struct S: PA, PB {
    func sayHello() { print("hello") }
}

func takesPB(_ thing: PB) {}

let s1: S = S()
let s2: PA = S()
takesPB(s1)  // No error
takesPB(s2)  // error: argument type 'PA' does not conform to expected type 'PB'
extension PA: PB {}  // error: extension of protocol 'PA' cannot have an inheritance clause
```

In this example, `PB` has no requirements, and it's therefore clear that any type conforming to `PA` — or, in fact, any type at all — should conform to `PB`. However, I can't find a way to express this relationship to the compiler.

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44425503/1292061), but the key difference here is that `PB` is a strict subset of `PA`, and I can therefore be sure that *any* type that does conform to `PA` also conforms (or at least can conform) to `PB`. Searching further, it appears this may also be a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41993616/1292061), though I'm not sure.

Note that in the interests of creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I've simplified the problem considerably.

Comment: Since you don't control `PA` how about just wrapping it ? `protocol PC: PA, PB {}`

Comment: I'm using APIs which I also don't control that return `PA` objects. I need to use those objects as `PB` objects, which should be valid, but I can't express that all `PA` are `PB`.

Comment: seems like there are more constraints than I imagined, maybe someone else here knows a good solution, but it sounds like you might have to copy `PA` as a `PB` so that you can use it as a `PB`.